# How do I play a video in UITableViewCell?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, video

How is this accomplished, Im trying to make a wall like twitters. I'm having an issue with adding the video inside the `cell`. I have looked everywhere and if someone can help that would be greatly appreciated.

Is the best way to add a subview to the `cell` then add the movie to the `subview`?

Please help (ripping hair out)!

Comment: Be sure you're adding subviews to the contentView of the cell.

Answer (score -1):

You cant play video inline in iOS . But there is one way to do it. It worked for me .

1. extract the video thumbnail from the video .
2. Add image view on your cell
3. show the video thumbnail on image view
4. Onclick of the cell the video will play in native player

Comment: I was able to add the video, However the table plays all the videos at once. I am trying to make a feed like twitter or instagram where the video is inside the cell. Do you know how to accomplish this?